# Allow macro to run through repeated steps on every tab within workbook

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to write a code that allows the macro to loop through every single tab within the workbook. The macro is adding all individual tabs worth of data into one tab. So its just copying and pasting rows of data. However, based on how my code is currently written, it needs to know the name of each individual tab. I am adding tabs to this sheet constantly so it's inefficient for me to update the code every time I need to run the macro. Any tips? Thanks!
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO6qB.png)

I've only tried to name each individual tab and write that tab name in the code. I think it might need a loop but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Please don't paste pictures of code - you can copy and paste it directly into your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Public Sub doTheJob()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   For Each ws In Worksheets
      If ws.Name <> "Export" Then
         Debug.Print ws.Name
         'YOUR CODE HERE FOR the ws Sheet, whitch is the "next" sheet in every loop
      End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I think I'm getting closer, but when I type that in it just keeps copying and pasting my "Export" tab. It doesn't go to the next tab and then next tab to get the data that needs to be copy and pasted.

Comment: Sheets("Export").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Dim ws As Worksheet
   For Each ws In Worksheets
      If ws.Name <> "Export" Then
         Debug.Print ws.Name
            Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Export").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
      End If
   Next

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to copy and paste the code correctly, which is why I took a screenshot.

Comment: please copy your code AS CODE no in comments. Edit your question:  paste two empty lines at the end, and after paste the code. Select the code and click on {} in the bar. Save the edits